# justify align multiline text input form in FPDM

Tags: php, forms, pdf

I have a form with some fields and when I submit I want to create a PDF with some info from the form. I started with FPDM library and it's great but the problem is that I can't justify the align of a big paragraph (which is really important to do) because PDFs with form don't allow a different align than center,left,right into text form fields..

Any Ideas about how to justify the paragraph with FPDM??? **thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dead simple to include a PHP variable into a string.

```
$pdf->Cell(190,8,$this_is_your_variable . ' and you can include text too',1,1,'L',1);
```

Comment: now it works! thanks!....I'm still interested if there is someone who knows how to justify the multiline input text using FPDM

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. [Here's how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/379718) and [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!